# Alias for imported namespace

Tags: c#, .net, alias, using

I'm working on a project using StyleCop to verify the coding style. It forces me to write my code as follows:

```
using AF.Data.Oracle
{
   using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; // *** Compile error here ***

   class Foo {}
}
```

But I constantly get an error telling that type 'DataAccess' could not be found in namespace 'AF.Data.Oracle'.

I know that I can use aliases for every type from Oracle.DataAccess.Client, but this would add several alias definitions.

But is it possible to use something like alias for a namespace?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`global` namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx):

```
namespace AF.Data.Oracle
{
   using global::Oracle.DataAccess.Client; 

   class Foo {}
}
```

This will avoid the namespace clash between `AF.Data.Oracle` and any namespace beginning with `Oracle` by ensuring you mean the `Oracle` that is at the namespace root.

Comment: Perhaps you could make it clear that he was experiencing a namespace clash (because AF.Data.Oracle is a closer match) and he needed to qualify the name in order to disambiguate